# Accessing Object from codebehind in asp.net

Tags: activex

I have a object as shown below for digital signature. How can I access it from codebehind. When I tried adding runat=server I am getting an error saying GUID cannot be more there 32 char and I am not able to access it from code behind.

```
<object height="113" width="225" id="IntegriSign1"  data="data:application/x-oleobject;base64,p0bAhHBDkU2HN4fBL0xjxQADAABBFwAArgsAABMAAAAAABMA////AA=="                                 classid="clsid:84C046A7-4370-4d91-8737-87C12F4C63C5" name="IntegriSign1">
```

This object is a COM component I added the dll reference.

Is there any way I can access it from the code behind. when I try to put runat=server I am getting the following error

Error   377 Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

Comment: What object do you mean? I think you haven't posted the entire question..

Comment: Fixed needed to escape the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can add run at server

```
<object id="items" class = "System.Collections.ArrayList"  runat="server" />
```

Please follow this link also

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/aspnet/syntax/server-sideobjecttagsglobalasax.aspx